# Why is statsmodels "Df Model" less than the number of model parameters included?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I've seen this issue arise in my coding a few times now where the "Df Model" that statsmodels calculates is smaller than the number of parameters fit by the model.

As far as I can tell it happens regardless of which model I fit and (I believe) only in cases with a not small (> ~20?) number of parameters.  Might this have something to do with high multicollinearity among the parameters?

Since this issue seems to arise with a large-ish number of parameters (with 'real' data), I'm not sure I can just recreate some dummy data to showcase the issue.  I'm simply hoping someone has seen it before and knows why it is occurring.

Regardless, a sample of my code (& output as comments) is shown below.

```
print type(base_features) #<type 'list'>
print len(base_features) #70

model = sm.GLM(train1['target'], train1[base_features], family=Poisson()) 
#^ produces the same results for other glm family models as well as standard OLS
poi_base = model.fit()

print len(poi_base.params) #70
print poi_base.df_model #63
```

Please note that there is a user constructed intercept/constant in 'base_features', but even if statsmodels was able to discern that, df_model should still be 69 at minimum.

Answer (score 1):

In general the df_model depends on the rank of the design matrix and does not take a constant into account. The rank is defined by the threshold used in numpy which depends on the condition number.

The linear models take into account whether a constant was detected to be among the `exog`, either explicitly or implicitly. Other models like those in discrete and GLM assume that there always is a constant. (In linear models the definition of `rsquared` depends on the presence of a constant, in other models `llnull` is the loglikelihood of the model with a constant only without checking whether the original model contains a constant or not.)

In linear models, OLS, WLS and similar

```
self._df_model = float(self.rank - self.k_constant)
```

In GLM

```
self.df_model = np_matrix_rank(self.exog) - 1
```

In discrete models, Logit, Probit, Poisson and similar

```
self.df_model = float(np_matrix_rank(self.exog) - 1)
```

(There are some open issues on github about the definitions of various `df_model` and `df_resid`, mainly for the treatment of the constant. For penalized estimator the df_model and df_resid should be based on effective degrees of freedom, but that might not be consistently implemented yet.)

Aside: Estimators based on linear models including those estimated by iteratively reweighted least squares are by default based on generalized inverse which produces an estimate even if the design matrix is rank deficient. All other models will break in the optimization and raise an exception with a singular design matrix.